# Can we make our Top Bar sticky?

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

The two SE sites that I visit the most are SFF and Stack Overflow. I'm not wild about the format of the new top bar, but it's good that all SE sites now have a similar top bar.

The only thing I really liked about SO's new top bar was the option to make it sticky (stay at the top of the window when you scroll down). SFF's new top bar is not sticky. Can we have an option to make it sticky like on Stack Overflow?

Comment: The new top bar seems incompatible with Stack Overflow Extras (which could make the bar sticky). My guess is that it'll start working again in a couple of days time and you'll be able to do this with or without SE support.

Comment: @Valorum Thanks for that! Stack Overflow Extras looks interesting and I would like to play around with it. I can install the script and get it to run, but it appears to be incompatible with the top bar on Stack Overflow (which has been around for months), so I'm not so sure it will be fixed in a couple of days.

Comment: My instinct is that they'll get it working again. It's too well liked for them to simply abandon

Comment: "*Can we make our Top Bar sticky?*" - sure! Just put some glue on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Stack Exchange Top Nav Choices

I just came across a userscript that allows for customisation of the top bar across all sites, called [Stack Exchange Top Nav Choices](https://stackapps.com/questions/7603/top-navigation-choices). It doesn't have all the cool features of *Stack Overflow Extras* (mentioned by Valorum in a comment on my question), but unlike *Stack Overflow Extras* it currently works with the new top bar.

It has options (that you set in your profile preferences) that can make the new top bar look like the old one (if you really don't like change), and it also allows you to optionally make the top bar sticky on all sites that use the new top bar.

Answer (score 5):

[This concern was brought up on Main Meta:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300865/310650)

> Please make the stickiness persistent, at least from main to meta if not network-wide
>
> I know that a network-wide flip for the stickiness is an, uh, sticky point, but I was pretty surprised to find the top-bar to stick to the top of the screen on meta.SO after I'd disabled that feature on SO itself. Add additional switches for meta if you want, but I think it's reasonable to assume that if a user has set the top bar as fixed on a given SE site, they also want it to stay put on the corresponding meta.

[And is under review by the SE Team.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live)

> Stickiness global preference
>
> Concern: SO top bar is sticky by default with a preference to unstick it. Network site top bar is not sticky by default and there is no way to make it so. Can we get a global preference for setting stickiness across all sites?
>
> Status: status-review
>
> Explanation: We think this is a good thing to have, now we just need to figure out how to make it so. This could be a somewhat expensive setting since we currently don't have any global settings. That said, we are actively investigating it.

I think we just to have wait until this is reviewed network wide.